# Send Notifications using target feeds with getstream.io

Tags: javascript, getstream-io

I've been working with getstream.io for a while
and currently I'm facing an issue with the notifications.

To start using notifications I thought it was easier to implement in reactions due to having the targetFeeds property, but I'm facing an access error. I'm trying achieve it doing the next.

```
UserA commenting in UserB publication

// Client is initialized with UserA info

const comment = await client.reactions.add('comment', activity.id, { data }, { targetFeeds: [`notifications:UserB.ID`] });
```

My question is how to send a notification to UserB notification feed.

The result I expect is userB receiving a notification like "userA has commented in your publication" or alike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue as first pointed by Sanchaz was that I was using `notifications` as slug for the notification feed instead of `notification`, I thought that wasn't the case because I created the notification feed with `notifications` slug.

StreamIO support stated that if the notification feed doesn't match `notification` slug, the default permissions doesn't apply, therefore the solution was to rename the slug from `notifications` to `notification`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the default feed for notifications is 'notification' (no s.)

Also I'm not fully aware of what you are tying to accomplish, but just a heads up there is also the TO field for targeting.

https://getstream.io/docs/targeting/?language=js

Comment: Yeah you are right but in my application I created a notification feed with the name notifications with S, that's why I'm using it that way.  And the goal is to notify user B that user A commented on a post user B published.

Comment: I post another comment to separate. The Targeting on the activity seems a bit different than reactions. Reactions suggest target Feed as in the code above. The issue here is that I'm getting a security error. And support hasn't answered yet if this is on their side or mine

Comment: Are you generating this client side or server side?

Also the target absolutely allows you to say which feed it should go to

`'to': ['feed:user']`
eg:
`to: ['notification:Jessica'],`

Comment: I get the keys and user token from backend, then I initialize client on frontend. And I believe the ```'to'``` key is only for activities. While reactions use ```targetFeeds``` according to their documentation.

Comment: notifications are made of activities, everything is an activity.

I'm not sure why you need to use a reaction. You said you wanted to send notifications.

Reactions are for more complex cases, where you have a comment within a feed item. An activity linked to another activity.

"When using reactions, it is possible to request enriched activities that include both attached reactions by type and reaction counters."


Can we see how you acquire your token in the backend?

Comment: That's precisely my case, I'm commenting in an activity, that's why I'm using reaction.
Your comment about ```to: ['notification:Jessica']``` was almost on point. It seems the issue is that they only allow some specific cases if it matches the name ```notification``` and not the feed type.

Comment: I can't comment on your solution, but can you expand on why the having it named notification instead of notifications matters?
Can't you choose the permissions when generating the token in the backend?

Comment: Sorry I thought I answered.

No you can't choose permissions on backend, it's on their side (I know, that's weird, I mean even they can set those restrictions based on feed type instead of the name notification).

It matters because of the way they built it.

Comment: https://getstream.io/docs_rest/#serverside_authentication
Is this not the permissions you are looking for on the backend?
You can define the resource and the action (read, write, delete, or all *)

{
    "resource": "follower",
    "action": "read",
    "feed_id": "user_timeline123"
}